# How to track steps with the iPhone Health app

Tags: iphone, health.app

I just got an iPhone 8 (iOS 11.4) and I can't figure out how to track the steps that I take everyday through the phone. Can I do it through the **Health** app by itself or do I need to use Strava or some other app to do so?

Looking at the Health app, it says I have no data for the year/month/week/day. I went to the **Data Sources & Access** tab but it doesn't list any apps, not even Strava or Pacer Pedometer. Pacer Pedometer was listed as a recommended app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Source](https://www.cultofmac.com/495026/how-to-activate-iphone-hidden-pedometer/):

1. Enable Motion Tracking, so that your iPhone will actually record the data.  Go to `Settings>Privacy>Motion & Fitness`.  Toggle `Fitness Tracking` on. Now your iPhone will count your steps.
   [image]
2. Go to the Health app to setup your physical info so that it can better estimate your stride length.
3. Add steps to the Today view.  While in Health app, go to the `Health Data` button at bottom left. Then tap `Activity` and scroll down until you find `Steps` and tap that. Toggle the `Add to Favorites` switch. Now you can view your step count easily from the `Today` screen.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Health Data tab on your Health app and tap on Fitness
2. Select Walking+Running
3. Then flip the switch for Show On Dashboard to the ON
4. Choose “Steps” and toggle “Show On Dashboard” to ON
5. Go to “Flights Climbed” and flip the same “Show On Dashboard” to ON
6. Tap back to the “Dashboard” tab in Health app to see the three functions and their respective charts